# issues Spotting the error

Tags: android-activity

The error that i'm getting is "Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete 
     ClassBody
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
     Statement
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
     Expression"
still on the same line i've tried placing different ")" and"}" and they just make it worse even tried playing around with removing or moving them around still same issue ..cannot run cause of the error

My `SignUp` class,

```
public  class SignUp extends Activity {
    private EditText reg_fullname, reg_username, reg_email, reg_password, reg_confirmpassword;
    private Button btnRegister;
    private LoginDataBaseAdapter dataBaseAdapter;
    private TextView loginScreen;
    protected DataBaseHelper DB = new DataBaseHelper(SignUp.this); 

@Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set View to register.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.signup);


     reg_fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_fullname);
     reg_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_username);
     reg_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
     reg_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
     reg_confirmpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_confirmpassword);

    loginScreen = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.link_to_login);
    //Listening to Login Screen Link
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    loginScreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


      switch(v.getId()){

      case R.id.link_to_login:
          startActivity(new Intent(SignUp.this, LoginScreen.class));
            finish();
            break;

      case R.id.btnRegister:
        // I think they have to be final to be used in the onClickListener
            final String fullname = reg_fullname.getText().toString();
            final String username = reg_username.getText().toString();
            final String password = reg_password.getText().toString();
            final String email = reg_email.getText().toString();

            boolean invalid = false;

       if(fullname.equals(""))
       {
        invalid = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter your Firstname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       else


        if(username.equals(""))
        {
         invalid = true;
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else


          if(password.equals(""))
         {
          invalid = true;
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
         else 
          if(email.equals(""))
       {
        invalid = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Email ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
         else
          if(invalid == false)
          {
           addEntry(fullname, username, password, email);
           Intent i_register = new Intent(SignUp.this, LoginScreen.class);
           startActivity(i_register);
           finish();

      }
      }
          break;
        } ****error appears here ***
    }
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try{
        super.onDestroy();
    dataBaseAdapter.close();
}catch(Exception e){
       Log.e("onDestroy SignUp- Error", e.getMessage());
}}

private void addEntry(String fullname,  String username, String password, String email) 
 {

      SQLiteDatabase db = DB.getWritableDatabase();

      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put("fullname", fullname);
      values.put("username", username);
      values.put("password", password);
      values.put("email", email);

      try
      {
       db.insert(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your details submitted Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }


 }}
```

Comment: What is the error?  Does it happen during run time or during compilation?  What have you tried so far?  To get better answers on Stack Overflow, you may want to read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Without loading up the code, it sounds like you're missing a closing bracket.  These are called `syntax errors`.  This [list of common Java Syntax Errors](http://northern.lkdsb.net/kedwell/ICS4U/Java/intro/Syntax%20Errors.htm) may be helpful to you.

Comment: it happens during the compilation.... ive tried inserting } in numerous places ... and it just creates more errors

Comment: Most of the time your IDE will give you an indication of where it's wrong.  Go through your code and check to make sure that every open bracket has a closing one. It may be tedious, but it is necessary.

Comment: alright i'm do that . but if i still cant find the issue is there something else i can do ?

Comment: Edit your question to be more specific.  Include the exact error message, when it happens, and what you've tried to do to fix it/what the results of that were.  A better formed question will get more attention.

Comment: Also indent your code while you create it. Use a good IDE to increase productivity.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following symbols after your break;:

```
      ...
      break;
    }
  });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
```